# Is it possible to read attributes of child elements from Razor?

Tags: c#, razor

As the title says, is there any way to read an attribute of an element in the DOM from an enclosing Razor statement? Something like (mashing in some jQuery syntax as I try to imagine what the syntax might be):

```
@if (CheckElementVisibility(childelements[0].data("elementid") == true)) 
{
    <input type="text" data-elementid="123" />
}
```

I realise that the best way would be write a custom HTML Helper but that's not really an option.

I doubt that what I'm asking is possible but I thought I'd ask anyway just in case anyone had a clever idea!

Comment: What exactly is your scenario? What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: It's not possible what you want to do. I would prefer you to implement the CheckElementVisibility Method as a javascript function. If that's not an option for you, let me know.

Comment: The question is mostly hypothetical but I was considering a way to pass an attribute of an element (e.g. `data-elementid`) to a function which would check against a Lookup of elements and permissions to determine whether the element should be rendered or not. @skipper I could use Javascript - we've already implemented Knockout so it'd be pretty straightfoward to bind the elements' visibility - but I liked the idea of the elements not being rendered at all under these circumstances rather than relying on Javascript to hide them.